# How to Properly install ForceWorkBench on self-hosted Ubuntu Linux Distro?

Tags: salesforcedx, workbench

I do apologize if this has already been asked (recently); I did search and could not find anything specifically dealing with **"How to" installations of WorkBench**.

A number of weeks ago in July 2023, workbench.developerforce.com was down.
It was suggested to try hosting it locally. So, I downloaded the code, and followed the somewhat cryptic instructions to get it installed.  However, after a few days of trying this, and trying that, I gave up.

Has anyone RECENTLY tried to download and install the Force Workbench code into a Ubuntu Linux Distro?? I'm not a Linux expert, but with 30 years IT experience, can follow directions pretty well.

Some of the conflicts I was running into, was after installing Ubuntu and updating all the latest security updates (apt update, apt upgrade), I could not find the magic combination of packages ( Apache, MySQL, Php) that allowed everything to run, without throwing an error that there was a conflict.

I have reviewed the [installation](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/wiki/#installation) wiki, and it does not speak of any of the version conflicts that I ran into.

If someone knows the magic steps ( in more detail ) to get this installed (start to finish), please let me know how and/or update the Wiki so that others don't run into this same problem that I did.

Thank you. And much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered the Salesforce Inspector and/or postman chrome extensions? Not the same as Workbench, and it does depend what you are doing, but may be useful.

Comment: I'm running an older copy on heroku, but I'll try and spin up a Ubuntu box and see what happens.

Comment: @PhilW - just looked at SF inspector... interesting tool, but not what I need workbench for. Also have used postman, great tool too. But I like workbench, because there's pretty much everything you need, in 1 tool. I don't have to go here for this, or there for that. And the bulk update/upsert data administration tools I haven't seen its equal anywhere else, especially for free.

Answer (score 3):

To get a copy running locally, here's the steps I fumbled through.

First, install Ubuntu, if needed. This answer applies to Ubuntu 22.04.3. I installed it using unattended mode in Virtualbox for this answer.

Next, download and extract the latest file from the [installation](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/tags) notes. I used the ZIP version, but this should hardly matter which one you choose.

Now, get into terminal and log in as superuser:

```
~/$ su
Password:
/home/brianfear/#
```

You'll know you're root because of the `#` at the end of the prompt, instead of `$`.

Next, we may need to install some stuff. It doesn't hurt to run these commands multiple times (e.g. some of them may have already been installed).

```
apt install php8.1

apt install php8.1-soap

apt install php8.1-curl
```

After that, we have to copy the `~/Downloads/forceworkbench-53.0.0/workbench` directory. Remember we're in superuser mode, so we need to use the appropriate home directory.

```
cp -r /home/brianfear/Downloads/forceworkbench-53.0.0/ /var/www/html/
```

PHP doesn't like missing required sources, so let's make an empty file.

```
mkdir /var/www/html/vendor
touch /var/www/html/vendor/autoinit.php
```

PHP 8 has removed the function `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`, so we need to update the source code.

```
find /var/www/html/workbench/ -type f | xargs sed -i  's/get_magic_quotes_gpc\(\)/false/g'
```

Or do this in an IDE. We're just replacing `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` with `false`, so the ternary operator will always take the false path. You can clean this up later if you'd like.

Now, you need to enable SOAP. Open `/etc/php8.1/apache2/php.ini`, find the line that reads `;extension=soap` and remove the `;`. Save your changes.

Now that we've done all this, you should be just about ready. Since we changed an ini file, we need to restart the server.

```
# systemctl restart apache2.server
```

If you've done all of this correctly, you should be able to click on this link: [Local Workbench](http://localhost/workbench/), and it'll take you to the login page.

I haven't tested every single page to see if there's any other missing dependencies, but I did test a number of pages, everything seems to be functional. If you get stuck or have other feedback, please feel free to reach out.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out this weekend, and get back to you!